# Netbeans not showing Known Archetypes with new Project from Archetype

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have a problem with **NetBeans** when I try to create a new project, it does not show all options of archetypes to create a project.

I work in Windows 10, and I already have added **maven** to the user path. It works when i use `mvn -v` in the Windows console.

[image: archetype screen]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem is produced because The Central Repository no longer supports insecure communication over plain HTTP and requires that all requests to the repository are encrypted over HTTPS.

To solve this, i have to modify the file "**NetbeansLocationPath/java/maven/conf/settings.xml**"
and add the next lines in the mirros tags.

```
    <mirror>
      <id>other-mirror</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <name>Other Mirror Repository</name>
      <url>http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <id>internal-repository</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Manager running on https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</name>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```